# how to properly insert baseurl in php

Tags: php, joomla

I have this PHP line of code

```
$url = 'index.php?' . JUri::buildQuery($uriQuery);
```

the result I get is:   `/index.php/my-article-1`

but I need my baseurl in front of `index.php`
so I try

```
$url = '//mysite.com/index.php?' . JUri::buildQuery($uriQuery);
```

but then the result is:    //mysite.com/index.php 
without following article alias

I need it to be `//mysite.com/index.php/my-article-1`

and I don't really know how to insert //mysite.com in front of `index.php` URL

I also have this js code if it matters

```
 url: baseUrl + "index.php?option=com_joomreminder&task=remind"
```

Comment: I doublt that the result of your first line of code is `/index.php/my-article-1`. Please read and describe carefully again what your precise problem is.

Comment: @Nula Please ask your Joomla-related questions at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.